# Binding a complex model to a drop down list in MVC

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to bind a model that has two properties - one Int, and one Boolean - to a drop-down list in MVC. The boolean is a discriminator and the integer an ID. It is not possible to split the drop down list in two.

Here is my code so far.

```
<select class="col-md-3 form-control" name="Model.ID" id="model-select">
    <option value="0" selected>Select an Option</option>
    @foreach (var m in models.OrderBy(x => x.Id))
    {
        <option value="@m.ID" data-discriminator="@m.Discriminator">
            @m.Name
        </option>
    }
</select>
```

The model looks something like this

```
class MyModel
{
  int ID { get; set; }
  string Name { get; set; }
  boolean Discriminator { get; set; }
}
```

The aim is to provide a set of models to the View, then the user can pick one of these. Unfortunately each model has two properties which are used to identify which model was selected in the database - the Id, which mirrors the Id in the database, and the Discriminator. The two types are otherwise incompatible in the database, hence the discriminator. For the sake of design, I only want to have these two in the same drop-down list, as you can only select one at a time anyway.

My idea of a solution was to create 2 hidden fields which would be bound to the model like so

```
<input type="hidden" name="Model.ID" />
<input type="hidden" name="Model.Discriminator" />
```

These would be updated via JavaScript and then bound to the model (as far as I know, using names like that will bind it correctly, providing that the destination property on the model passed to the POST is Model in this example).

Are there any other alternatives I could pursue?

EDIT: Also worth noting that this 'Model' is part of a more complex model and is not the only field being POSTed, so if that makes any difference...

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. The ID alone would be enough to select this very simple entity, and discriminators aren't booleans, since the whole point of a discriminator is to bind the data to a specific type, which can't be determined from a boolean value. What are you *actually* trying to achieve, because I'm sure there's a better way.

Comment: `The ID alone would be enough to select this very simple entity`

No, it wouldn't. The ID binds to a database entity - the boolean is a switch that indicates whether it is an ID bound to table A or table B. I am trying to create a drop-down list that contains both entities from A and B and be able to discriminate them on the controller side.

Comment: And, no, I cannot change the database design, it's not up to me - it was before my time. And why are you saying a boolean cannot be a discriminant? Of course it can - as long as a) they types are known and b) there are two.

Comment: Well, see you didn't mention the fact that there's two tables involved. That's kind of important information.

Comment: `The two types are otherwise incompatible in the database, hence the discriminator`. Also I thought it could have been inferred by the boolean, but whatever. No point bickering over it

Comment: The discriminator usually works in reverse, specifically for single-table inheritance, where data from multiple types exists in a single database and the purpose of the discriminator is to differentiate between those sibling types. Using a discriminator at a class level to determine which of a set of tables to pull from is pretty much unheard of, mostly because you can't have any true relationships (foreign keys) and one type is pretty incapable of representing two distinct tables for any useful purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A select box is only going to be able to post one thing, and using JavaScript to populate hidden fields, while perhaps a workable solution, seems very brittle. Your best bet would like be creating an intermediary property that you can bind to and include both sets of information  as the option value:

```
public string SelectedThing
{
    get { return string.Format("{0},{1}", ID, Discriminator); }
    set
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            var parts = value.Split(',');
            if (parts.Length == 2)
            {
                Int32.TryParse(parts[0], out ID);
                Boolean.TryParse(parts[1], out Discriminator);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you would need to compose your select list in a similar way:

```
ViewBag.MyModelChoices = myModels.Select(m => new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = string.Format("{0},{1}", m.ID, m.Discriminator),
        Text = m.Name
    });
```

And finally, you would bind to this new property in your view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedThing, ViewBag.MyModelChoices)
```

Comment: Eventually ended up going with this with a formatted string.